# Get connectionString for current DB

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to find out `connectionString` which would be like: `TestDB.Properties.Settings.TestDBConnectionString` ([according to this video](https://youtu.be/p2UeT7dBTEg?t=3m46s)), but I'm working with `WPF` and there is no `<connectionStrings>` in `App.config`.

I looked at properties of my DB and there was `Connection String` such as `Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=//path_to_file//TestDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True` - but it's not the same type was mentioned above. And it won't work for my connection below.

I'm trying to connect like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        string connectionString;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["data_here"].ConnectionString;
        }
```

Comment: So put the connection string in the web.config if that's what you want? I don't get what you're asking.

Comment: You've meant I have to put `<connectionStings><add name="TestDB.Properties.Settings.TestDBConnectionString" ...` in `App.config` and than use it?

Comment: I don't know. That's up to you. If you want the connection string to be in the app.config file, that's how you do it. And your name doesn't have to nearly so complex. Simply `TestDbConnectionString` should be plenty.

Comment: Thanks, I hope I get you. `name` it's like simplified path.

Comment: No, it's not a path at all. It's merely a name. So long as the strings match up, they can be anything. Therefore it makes sense to keep it short but still express what it's used for.

Comment: Name is... *the name* of the connection string, other properties are the value that will be accessible via name.

Comment: What do you mean by "current DB"?

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/ is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for are `ApplicationSettings`.

You could create thos via `RightClick on your WPF-Project`->`Add`-> `Application Settings`.

[image]

In there you can add `ConnectionStrings`

[image]

You could use it like this:

```
string con = YourProjectNamespace.Properties.Settings.Default.YourSettingsPropertyKey;
```

**OR**

you add them manually to your `app.config`-file:

```
<configuration>     
   <startup>
     <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
   </startup>
   <connectionStrings>
      <add name="NameOfConnectionString" connectionString="actualConnectionString" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
   </connectionStrings>  
 </configuration>
```

You can access them like this:

```
 string appName = "YourAppName.exe";
 Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(appName);
 ConnectionStringsSection section = config.GetSection("connectionStrings") as ConnectionStringsSection;
 string x = section.ConnectionStrings["nameofyourConnectionstring"];
```

If you need help creating working connectionstrings visit [ConnectionStrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/)